# Finding the id of a parent div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, semantics

I have some html like this:

```
<div id="1">
    <p>
        Volume = <input type="text" />
        <button rel="3.93e-6" class="1" type="button">Check answer</button>
    </p>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

and some JS like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var buttonNo = $(this).attr('class');
    var correct = Number($(this).attr('rel'));

    validate (Number($("#"+buttonNo+" input").val()),correct);
    $("#"+buttonNo+" div").html(feedback);
});
```

What I'd really like is if I didn't have to have the class="1" on the button (I know numeric classes aren't valid, but this is a WIP!), so I could determine buttonNo based on the id of the parent div. In real life there are multiple sections looking like this.

1. How do I find the id of the div parenting the button.
2. What would be a more semantic way to store the answer in the button code. I want to make this as foolproof as possible for a non programmer to copy and paste without breaking things!

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You could use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on the parent div. Or use the [closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) method to find the parent of the button.

The easiest of the two is probably the closest.

```
var id = $("button").closest("div").prop("id");
```

Comment: I really like closest because you can do something like .closest("div.foo") and code is not tied to the structure.

Comment: Thx i was about to do a recursive function ....then i knew jquery had something already... in my case i used   $("#" + id).closest("div.form-group") to find the parent div who had the form-group class.

Answer (score 47):

1.

```
$(this).parent().attr("id");
```

2.

There must be a large number of ways! One could be to hide an element that contains the answer, e.g.

```
<div>
    Volume = <input type="text" />
    <button type="button">Check answer</button>
    <span style="display: hidden">3.93e-6&lt;/span>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

And then have similar jQuery code to the above to grab that:

```
$("button").click(function () 
{
    var correct = Number($(this).parent().children("span").text());
    validate ($(this).siblings("input").val(),correct);
    $(this).siblings("div").html(feedback);
});
```

bear in mind that if you put the answer in client code then they can see it :) The best way to do this is to validate it server-side, but for an app with limited scope this may not be a problem.

Comment: I have no idea how to format HTML in this editor, but this seems a rather simpler way to grab the parent than Pim's ('div:eq(0)') stuff; unless I'm missing a subtlety here then html elements all have one direct parent, which you just get with parent().

Comment: parent will indeed return the closest parent, however, what happens if he decides that he wants to add a fieldset or something around the question but inside the Div.

Comment: Actually in his own example this will return the <p>

Comment: Indeed, if more divs add in then the 'div:eq(0)' could be wrong. Change the structure, change the code that parses it :)

And yeah I simplified the example to the minimum html necessary for the example; it should call parent twice.

Comment: For some reason when I used parent() I could not access attr(id), i had to wrap the result like this `$(parent[0]).attr('id')` after I did like a few parent selectors.

Comment: instead of parent(), using parent('div') gives proper result

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).parents("div:first").html(...);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$(this).parents('div').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 7):

To get the id of the parent div:

```
$(buttonSelector).parents('div:eq(0)').attr('id');
```

Also, you can refactor your code quite a bit:

```
$('button').click( function() {
 var correct = Number($(this).attr('rel'));
 validate(Number($(this).siblings('input').val()), correct);
 $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').html(feedback);
});
```

Now there is no need for a button-class

**explanation**
eq(0), means that you will select one element from the jQuery object, in this case element 0, thus the first element. http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index
$(selector).siblings(siblingsSelector) will select all siblings (elements with the same parent) that match the siblingsSelector http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings#expr
$(selector).parents(parentsSelector) will select all parents of the elements matched by selector that match the parent selector. http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents#expr
Thus: $(selector).parents('div:eq(0)'); will match the first parent div of the elements matched by selector.

You should have a look at the jQuery docs, particularly selectors and traversing:

- http://docs.jquery.com/
- http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors
- http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing

Comment: Simple and easy! Why the div:eq(0)? What's that mean?

Comment: I think the 'div:eq(0)' will be wrong if this is all wrapped in at least one div, because you're doing an absolute traversal of the DOM rather than a relative one. Which would be fine if the first element were the "closest" parent, but this suggests otherwise: http://tinyurl.com/bbegow

Comment: (hence my use of parent() instead)

Answer (score 6):

http://jsfiddle.net/qVGwh/6/
Check this

```
   $("#MadonwebTest").click(function () {
    var id = $("#MadonwebTest").closest("div").attr("id");
    alert(id);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be easily done by doing:

```
$(this).closest('table').attr('id');
```

You attach this to any object inside a table and it will return you the id of that table.

Answer (score 3):

JQUery has a .parents() method for moving up the DOM tree you can start there.

If you're interested in doing this a more semantic way I don't think using the REL attribute on a button is the best way to semantically define "this is the answer" in your code.  I'd recommend something along these lines:

```
<p id="question1">
    <label for="input1">Volume =</label> 
    <input type="text" name="userInput1" id="userInput1" />
    <button type="button">Check answer</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="answer1" name="answer1" value="3.93e-6" />
</p>
```

and

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var correctAnswer = $(this).parent().siblings("input[type=hidden]").val();
    var userAnswer = $(this).parent().siblings("input[type=text]").val();
    validate(userAnswer, correctAnswer);
    $("#messages").html(feedback);
});
```

Not quite sure how your validate and feedback are working, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

find() and closest() seems slightly slower than:

```
$(this).parent().attr("id");
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().attr("id");`?