# jQuery: get parent, parent id?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id ="myList">
<li><a href="www.example.com">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the id of the ul (myList) using jQuery? My j-script event is triggered when the a link is clicked. I have tried:

```
$(this).parent().attr('id');
```

But it gets the id of the li, I need to go one higher, and I cant attach the click to the li either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the id of a parent div using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545978/finding-the-id-of-a-parent-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
```

Is how you would get the id of the parent's parent.

EDIT:

```
$(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
```

Is a more foolproof solution for your case.

Comment: calling parent. twice is neither efficient not future proof

Comment: `parent().parent()` is definitely faster than `parents('ul')` as the latter will search all the way up to the <html> tag looking for <ul> tags and return all of them. `closest('ul')` is a good choice because it stops searching after the first occurrence, but closest also includes the element it is being called on. Perhaps `$(this).parent().closest('ul')` is the best choice, unless the `$(this)` will never be a <ul>.

Comment: Agreed that 'closest' is the ideal approach.  Did not realize it at first, but any selector can work in place of 'ul'.

Answer (score 15):

```
 $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here are 3 examples:**

```js
$(document).on('click', 'ul li a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var example1 = $(this).parents('ul:first').attr('id');
    $('#results').append('<p>Result from example 1: <strong>' + example1 + '</strong></p>');

    var example2 = $(this).parents('ul:eq(0)').attr('id');
    $('#results').append('<p>Result from example 2: <strong>' + example2 + '</strong></p>');
  
    var example3 = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
    $('#results').append('<p>Result from example 3: <strong>' + example3 + '</strong></p>');
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id ="myList">
  <li><a href="www.example.com">Click here</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="results">
  <h1>Results:</h1>
</div>
```

Let me know whether it was helpful.