# how to check parent's parent's id equals

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="productmenu">
    <li>
      <a ref="#"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

how to check if a link's parent's parent has got an id = "productmenu"? I tried with PrentNode, but it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10260683/779158

Comment: alert($('a').parent().parent().prop('id'));

Answer (score 1):

```
var pid = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
```

Comment: I don't understand why you provided that link ?

Comment: Hi thx for your replay. But the structure is actuall `<ul id="productmenu">
    <li>
      <a ref="#"></a><ul></ul>
    </li>
</ul>` It is a sub menu. Seems like closet('ul') does not work here. Can I use something else instead?

Comment: Looking at your structure....  `closest` should work.. can you create a fiddle to show what is the problem.

Comment: have u find any difference between your answer and link provided by me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).closest("ul").attr("id") == "productmenu"){
}
```

Comment: Hi thx for your replay. But the structure is actuall `<ul id="productmenu">
    <li>
      <a ref="#"></a><ul></ul>
    </li>
</ul>` It is a sub menu. Seems like closet('ul') does not work here. Can I use something else instead?

Comment: Did you try it? it works on my side..:) closest("ul") will get the nearest "ul" elemenent upwards.