# how to get the parent div value by using third child class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, parents

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">success</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click the third `div`, for example  `$(.three).click(function (){ });`
I need the class of the parent `div` (`.one`). How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: refff

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545978/finding-the-id-of-a-parent-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

try with: `$('.three').parents('.one')`
or with `$('.three').closest('.one')`

from the DOCS: http://api.jquery.com/parents/
from the DOCS: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `.parent().parent()`, e.g. `$(".three").parent().parent().anything(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would be:

```
$(this).closest(".outer");
```

so:

```
$(".anyDepth").click(function () { 
    $(this).closest(".outermostDiv").addClass("foo");
});
```

Comment: THANKS BUDDIES I AM EXPECTING UR CONTINUE SERVICES