# How to find attribute of parent div

Tags: jquery

I am adding a button using append. How can find its parent div id (removeID) value so I can remove only that particular section?

```
$("#CCcontainer").append("<div id ="+removeID +" ><div class =\"form-group col-sm-10\"></div><div class =\"form-group col-sm-2\"><button type=\"button\" id=\"removeCard\"  class=\"btn btn-warning form-control\">Remove Card</button></div></div>");

$(document).on('click','#removeCard',function () 
{
    uniqueId--;
    alert("Removing" +("#CCPanel" + uniqueId) );

    $("#CCPanel" + uniqueId).remove();
    $("#removeCard"+ uniqueId).remove();
});
```

The above code is removing the button always from bottom. If I clicked on remove button in the middle, last one is getting deleted. I am trying to see if I can track the id of the clicked button so I can remove only that specific section.

Is there any way I can always maintain the sequence order? Like if I add 4 sections and removed second and then add one more time I should see sequence 4 not 5.

Go to my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/13/) and click **[Add Another Card button]** (Orange Button) to see how it works.

Comment: please look below thread

>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545978/finding-the-id-of-a-parent-div-using-jquery

Comment: parent or closet both are not working. Please help.

Comment: do you use firebug? can you please check what is happening through firebug

Comment: Actually I solved the problem. I have updated the HTML in append by adding an id for parent div tag and using parent method. Fiddle updated. But i still have another question. How can maintain the sequence ?http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/14/

Comment: @user3067524 - I fixed your issue right before you posted this. I've optimized your code and it maintains sequence. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21339821/682480.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've fixed your issue.  You don't need `.parent()` or `.closest()`. You simply needed to retain a reference to your top level container and then based on the extraction of the id on the button that was clicked, you can simply remove all children of the container that end with that id number.

Here's what I did:

```js
$('#AddCC').click(function () {

    uniqueId++;

    var container = $("#CCcontainer"),
        copyDiv = $("#CCPanel").clone(),
        divID = "CCPanel" + uniqueId,
        removeID = "RemoveCard" + uniqueId;

    copyDiv.attr('id', divID);

    container.append(copyDiv);
    container.append("<div id =" + removeID + " ><div class =\"form-group col-sm-10\"></div><div class =\"form-group col-sm-2\"><button id=\"btn" + removeID + "\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-warning form-control\">Remove Card</button></div></div>");

    $('#' + divID).find('input,select').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + uniqueId);
    });

    $("#" + removeID).find("button").on("click", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("btnRemoveCard", "");
        container.find("div[id$='" + id + "']").remove();
    });
});
```

### ***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/Jm2mW/)***

## UPDATE

The fiddle now has been updated to include code that will save the unique ids of the panels that are used.  It includes a hidden input field that simply stored an array of the ids.  It's defaulted to 1 since the first panel is already on the screen.

```
<input id="hiddenStoredPanelsArray" type="hidden" value="[1]" />
```

In the updated JavaScript you'll notice that I left `console.log` statements in there so you can see what happens to the array as you add and remove panels.

```
$('#AddCC').click(function () {

    uniqueId++;

    var container = $("#CCcontainer"),
        hidden = $("#hiddenStoredPanelsArray"),
        storedPanels = hidden.length ? $.parseJSON(hidden.val()) : null,
        copyDiv = $("#CCPanel").clone(),
        divID = "CCPanel" + uniqueId,
        removeID = "RemoveCard" + uniqueId;

    console.log(storedPanels);
    storedPanels.push(uniqueId);
    hidden.val(JSON.stringify(storedPanels));
    console.log(storedPanels);

    copyDiv.attr('id', divID);

    container.append(copyDiv);
    container.append("<div id =" + removeID + " ><div class =\"form-group col-sm-10\"></div><div class =\"form-group col-sm-2\"><button id=\"btn" + removeID + "\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-warning form-control\">Remove Card</button></div></div>");

    $('#' + divID).find('input,select').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + uniqueId);
    });

    $("#" + removeID).find("button").on("click", function () {
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace("btnRemoveCard", "")),
            hidden = $("#hiddenStoredPanelsArray"),
            storedPanels = hidden.length ? $.parseJSON(hidden.val()) : null,
            index = storedPanels == null ? -1 : storedPanels.indexOf(id);

        console.log(storedPanels);
        if (index > -1)
            storedPanels.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(storedPanels);

        container.find("div[id$='" + id.toString() + "']").remove();
        hidden.val(JSON.stringify(storedPanels));
    });
});
```

Comment: Any sample code please ? I used closet for now but geting undefined. I would like to try using parent but need a sample.  http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/13/

Comment: Thank you for your time and I appreciate you rhelp. I think I still see a small issue. I have added 4 times, removed second seaction then added again and try to remove the last one that I have added. But nothing is happening.

Comment: I have tested again to make sure I see correct. Yes If you add couple of times and remove one in between and then add, the one we added last cannot be deleted. But by clicking other remove button, don't know exactly, removing two sections at a time i guess.

Comment: @user3067524 - Ok, I've fixed the bug.  I just needed to remove the `uniqueId--;` from the remove card button click.  Now you can add 2,3,4, remove 3, leaving 1,2,4, add 5,6,7, remove 6, leaving 1,2,4,5,7.  That's how you wanted it, yes?

Comment: Can 1,2,4,5,7 becomes 1,2,3,4,5 ? Thanks!

Comment: @user3067524 - Can you explain why that's needed?  Why rename ids on controls that are already on the page?  They are still in order.  There's nothing on the page that uses that number visually that I can see.

Comment: Sure. Finally when submit, on server, I can look for ex : CCname1, CCName2 etc. if section 1 removed I may not get value for that.

Comment: @user3067524 - Right, but why would you be going in numerical order versus looping through the actual existing objects?  Or do what I did in the click handler.  Simply remove the prefix of the control and you have the `uniqueId` that was used.

Comment: on server request.getParameter("?????"); not knowing 1 or 2 how can I get the value of that element ?

Comment: I am thinking to submit the whole form to server. If you think there would be anothe ridea or sequencing correct before submiting that would be great!

Comment: @user3067524 - You wouldn't know the number no matter if they were in order or not, right?  I would just submit the whole form to the server.  If you don't want to do that, you could create a hidden input that contains a string array that holds all the ids.  You add the id in the add click and you remove the id in the remove click.  Then you call your getParameter for the array field, parse, and now you have the ids to use for getting the specific controls.

Comment: I like the hidden input idea. But I may need your help on how to add and remove id's to that. Thank you!

Comment: @user3067524 - I'll try to help you when I get a chance.

Comment: @user3067524 - Ok, answer has been updated. I hope you like it. All you should need to do now is post that hidden input field, parse it on the server, and you have your unique ids that you can use to pull each specific panel and their elements.

Comment: Awesome!!!!. Thank you verymuch. Really great help. You sepnt lot of time on this. I really appreciate it.Again Thank you. My Best Regards.

Comment: HI, Can you explain me below two lines when you get a chance?index = storedPanels == null ? -1 : storedPanels.indexOf(id);container.find("div[id$='" + id.toString() + "']").remove(); - what is "id$ do in find method?

Comment: @user3067524 - The first line checks to make sure `storedPanels` has a value.  If not, it sets `index = -1`.  If it has a value, it retrieves the `index` of the `id` in the `storedPanels` array.

Comment: @user3067524 - The second line searches the `container` object for all divs ending with the id of `id.toString()` and then consequently removes them from the DOM.  So to answer your question, `id$=`, means `id ending with`.  If it were `id^=` it would be search for an `id beginning with`.  It's regular expression syntax.

Comment: @user3067524 - Oh ... and you can always *upvote* any answer that helps you to show your appreciation. I know I would be appreciative of your appreciation =D

Comment: Hi there, Today I found a performance issue. I am using IE 9. Once i have mu hope page up, if i click addAnother card button, it it not responding for at least 8 to 10 sec. if I click again after 10 sec, then addButton is working.This is happening only firsttime when application opened firttime and then click the AddButton. Any suggetions please? Thanks!

Comment: I have posted new question on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579276/jquery-clone-performnace-issue?noredirect=1#comment32596867_21579276

Answer (score 0):

I think what fits best (if I understand) to its context is the closest function, it gets the first parent that matches the passed selector

```
.closest("#removeId");
```

Comment: I used closer but i am geting undefined. Fiddle updated.http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/13/