# how to get id of the div pressed

Tags: javascript, html

i need the id of the div that is pressed, my code looks like this right now, how do i get it?

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("one").onclick = call;
    document.getElementById("two).onclick = call;
}

function call () {
     var id = I need the id here.....
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the id of a parent div using Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545978/finding-the-id-of-a-parent-div-using-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

Answer (score 0):

The `call` function will be invoked with the `event` object as an argument. `event.target` will return the original element on which the event occurred. You can get the ID of that element using `event.target.id`.

Also, I don't think your code works because there's a missing quote on your second `document.getElementById`.

```
function call(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
}
```